# Magento 2 Custom Product type similar like Configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I am trying to create my own custom product type which basic functionalities are similar to the configurable products. So to achieve it

`product_type.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="deal_product_type" label="Deal Product Type" modelInstance="Eguana\DealProduct\Model\Product\Type\DealProductType" indexPriority="60" sortOrder="80" isQty="true">
        <priceModel instance="Eguana\DealProduct\Model\Product\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`DealProductType` class is

```
class DealProductType extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable 
{
    /**
     * Product type code
     */
    const TYPE_ID = 'deal_product_type';
}
```

Here I have extended it with the configurable products type class. Because  in mostly tutorials I have read if you want any core type functionality then extend with that. Such as explained [here](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2)

After implementing the mentioned article I can successfully add the product from admin. But it is not similar to the configurable. Such as I can not see the 'Configurations' section. Can you please help me? Thank you very much.